# Wordpress & php user agents not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm giving minor specific changes to each web browser for my websites main css sheet.

Here is my user agent code:

```
    $user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform    =   "css/common";

    $os_array       =   array(
            '/windows nt 10.0/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'css/windows',
            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'css/windows',
            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'css/osx',
            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'css/osx'
                        );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $os_platform    =   $value;
        }

    }   

    return $os_platform;

}

function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        =   "_changes.css";

    $browser_array  =   array(
            '/msie/i'       =>  '_ie.css',
            '/firefox/i'    =>  '_ff.css',
            '/safari/i'     =>  '_safari.css',
            '/chrome/i'     =>  '_chrome.css'
                        );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $browser    =   $value;
        }

    }

    return $browser;

}

$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();

echo $user_os,$user_browser;
```

However once I insert it into the wordpress header it defaults to some unknown user agent, causing "css/common_changes.css" to appear instead of "css/osx_safari.css" in my case.

Is there a known issue for using the php user agent code within wordpress?

Comment: wordpress does some browser detection already see https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-browser-detection/

Comment: this looks a lot like this -- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/allow-http_user_agent-to-collect-data-from-users

Comment: Thank you @dboals - followed their advice and got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Followed the provided website from @dboals comment.